# Dealing with Flexbox in tablet views

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been brought in to help deal with a rendering issue with a website. Specifically, a flexbox element goes all wonky when displayed on tablets. Desktop testing has shown that the issue only crops up when the width and height of the page are set to, say, iPad or iPad Pro in chrome dev tools.

has a section called "Our Top Areas Of Practice". In a desktop or mobile view this section works beautifully but at 768x1024 this section is stuck in a column to the right of the viewport. Any ideas on what would make Flexbox go all wonky like this?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in a minimal example?

Comment: I wish. We're using a theme called AVada that's a mess of shortcodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css that would center the elements

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
      .fusion-layout-column .fusion-column-content-centered {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .fusion-layout-column .fusion-column-content-centered .fusion-column-content {
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
```

Comment: So, your solution fixes the issue by avoiding flexbox. Do you think the issue is a rendering bug or buggered CSS on the website?

Comment: I checked it different sizes of windows